# phpmyadmin в docker и LEMP на сервере

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, phpmyadmin, mariadb

У меня есть oracle linux с mariadb+nginx+phpmyadmin+php-fpm+php7
В конфиге nginx есть как 80 так и 443
Мне надо развернуть phpmyadmin в docker и "подружить" его с mariadb, чтобы из phpmyadmin из докера в https открывалась уже созданая база с сервера

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то есть пачка докер контейнеров, которые надо каким-то образом связать так чтобы они видели друг друга и один из них торчал в вашу сеть. Если правильно помню то для связи контейнеров друг с другом есть специальные сети вот обзорная ссылка https://docs.docker.com/network/ . Там будет а-ля создать сеть, добавить контейнеры в сеть и прописать айпишники. Для того чтобы выставить порт можно как вариант прописать docker run с параметром -p.

Comment: Нет, есть db на хосте. Надо к ней подключиться с помощью phpmyadmin, который находится в контейнере докера. Докер находится на этом же хосте.

Comment: ты по идее можешь в докере айпишник хоста ввести и вроде он правильно смаршутизирует

Comment: хмм, я попробую

Comment: Надо было открыть порт 3306 в фаерволе)